# Creating one GroupBy object from another GroupBy object

Tags: python, pandas

I grouped df by a column of interest:

```
grouped = df.groupby('columnA')
```

Now I want to retain only the groups with at least 5 members:

```
grouped.filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 5)
```

If I try:

```
df2  = grouped.filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 5)
```

I'm getting a DataFrame, not a GroupBy object. So how can I retain my GroupBy object after performing filtering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One workaround is to call `groupby` method on the filtered data frame

```
grouped = grouped.filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 5).groupby('columnA')
```